# R : How can i find the maximum value in one column

Tags: r

i have a data frame like this

```
  v1    v2  v3
A332    as  1
A333    sm  0.75
A333    lx  0.25
A334    as  0.25
A334    sm  0.25
A334    tp  0.2
A334    dp  0.2
A334    lp  0.1
A335    dp  0.5
A335    tp  0.5
```

I want to chose the max value of V3 for V1  and  get the following matrix, if there are more than 1 max value then i would like to keep them all. and get the following matrix

```
  v1    v2  v3
A332    as  1
A333    sm  0.75
A334    as  0.25
A334    sm  0.25
A335    dp  0.5
A335    tp  0.5
```

and after this i would like to arrange this way

```
  v1    v2  v3      v2  v3   v2  v3
A332    as  1               
A333    sm  0.75    as  0.25        
A334    sm  0.25    dp  0.5  tp  0.5
```

how can i do it with R, any package can i use ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you explain the last arrangement further?

Comment: For the first subset `df[ave(df$V3, df$V1, FUN=function(x) x==max(x)),]`

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, `ave` should work:

```
ind <- ave(df$v3, df$v1, FUN = max) == df$v3
df[ind,]
```

For the second part, I'd just make a list with `split`:

```
split(df, df$v1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question can achieved with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  filter(v3 == max(v3))

# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# Groups: v1 [4]
# 
#       v1     v2    v3
#   (fctr) (fctr) (dbl)
# 1   A332     as  1.00
# 2   A333     sm  0.75
# 3   A334     as  0.25
# 4   A334     sm  0.25
# 5   A335     dp  0.50
# 6   A335     tp  0.50
```

For the second part, I believe this may be what you want and it can be achieved with `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  filter(v3 == max(v3)) %>%
  mutate(v1_v2 = paste(v1, v2, sep = "-")) %>%
  select(-v1, -v2) %>%
  spread(v1_v2, v3)

# Source: local data frame [4 x 7]
# 
#       v1 A332-as A333-sm A334-as A334-sm A335-dp A335-tp
#  (fctr)   (dbl)   (dbl)   (dbl)   (dbl)   (dbl)   (dbl)
# 1   A332       1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
# 2   A333      NA    0.75      NA      NA      NA      NA
# 3   A334      NA      NA    0.25    0.25      NA      NA
# 4   A335      NA      NA      NA      NA     0.5     0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `aggregate` or `tapply`

```
#recreate dataset
df = data.frame(t(matrix(nrow=3,data=c(
"A332",    "as",  1,
"A333",    "sm",  0.75,
"A333",    "lx",  0.25,
"A334",    "as",  0.25,
"A334",    "sm",  0.25,
"A334",    "tp",  0.2,
"A334",    "dp",  0.2,
"A334",    "lp",  0.1,
"A335",    "dp",  0.5,
"A335",    "tp",  0.5))))
names(df)=c("v1","v2","v3")
df$v3 = as.numeric(as.vector(df$v3))


aggregate(df[,3],by=df[,1:2],max)
     v1 v2    x
1  A332 as 1.00
2  A334 as 0.25
3  A334 dp 0.20
4  A335 dp 0.50
5  A334 lp 0.10
6  A333 lx 0.25
7  A333 sm 0.75
8  A334 sm 0.25
9  A334 tp 0.20
10 A335 tp 0.50

tapply(X=df[, 3], INDEX=list(df$v1, df$v2), FUN=max)
       as  dp  lp   lx   sm  tp
A332 1.00  NA  NA   NA   NA  NA
A333   NA  NA  NA 0.25 0.75  NA
A334 0.25 0.2 0.1   NA 0.25 0.2
A335   NA 0.5  NA   NA   NA 0.5
```